# Less confusing icons for localized Stack Overflow sites

Tags: feature-request, design, favicon, portuguese-stackoverflow, russian-stackoverflow

Currently the following icons are used for PT.SO and RU.SO:

<kbd>[image: Pt.SO]</kbd> <kbd>[image: Ru.SO]</kbd>

In case they are changed, here is what they are as of posting this:

<kbd>[image: Pt.SO as posted]</kbd> <kbd>[image: Ru.SO as posted]</kbd>

And what they became later:

<kbd>[image: Pt.SO later]</kbd> <kbd>[image: Ru.SO later]</kbd>

Portuguese is green, Russian is blue. What these colors are supposed to mean? Random colors from the flags of the corresponding countries?

I suggest using language codes instead: **PT** and **RU**. These symbols are easy to add even to the tiniest 16x16 px icons:

[image: Small text suggestion]

If the characters are easy to recognize even on 16x16 px icons, there won't be any issues with bigger icons either.

Comment: Good point. It shouldn't be based on flag - for example, there are more Chinese speakers of BrE than British ones. That's no reason to make an english site have the chinese flag - but neither should it have the Union flag.

Comment: What about **R**ed for **R**ussia, **P**urple for **P**ortugal

Comment: The point is, why are they in different sizes?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 Portuguese SO is getting a new design when it graduates, [so it’s stuck on the old SO theme and logo for now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252749/226928). Russian and Japanese SO both went straight to the new design.

Comment: There was [a similar suggestion on Meta PT.SO](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/546/74). Personally, I prefer the colors. Although still not great, it's visually better than the language codes.

Comment: @Tim I believe green was chosen for PT.SO because it's both on the Brazil flag and the Portugal flag.

Comment: @bfavaretto quite possibly, but still. Most english speakers are in England / America, and yes [so] isn't red/blue/white (and shouldn't be, even if it was second) because of the number of non english / american english speakers.

Comment: @bfavaretto Some people (~8% of men) are colorblind. And even if you don't care about them, there will be more and more localized SO sites. How easy will it be to distinguish and remember icons with 10 colors?

Comment: As a source of inspiration, here are some localized icons from German translation site dict.leo.org: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OSjTU.png

Comment: @Vlad I'm afraid not all Russians would appreciate ushanka stereotype. :)

Comment: @Athari: well, we could go ahead and gather all the stereotypes. (Multiple icons, randomly changed?) Perhaps this way people would learn what other countries think about them?

Comment: If you upgrade these two icons you should change all Localised StackOverflow sites to include the new style :). I like the new icons!

Comment: I agree that colors probably aren't the best way to distinguish them, but tiny little letters that no one can read in a little 16x16 icon is an even worse way to distinguish them. The difference needs to be more blatantly obvious than that.

Comment: @animuson I don't insist letters are the only difference between the logos. "Box" or "stack" can be colored differently, for example. This way, icons will be easy to distinguish and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly flag colors aren't going to make it. There are multiple countries that have very similar colors so a little text right next to the box should be very acceptable. Just add the appropriate text according to language and you should be done! Anyways, languages don't have colors, only countries, and languages are spoken all over the world, making colors much less appropriate.

- Spanish - SP/ES
- Portuguese - PT
- Russian - RU

etc. The change must be made before any last minute protests (literally) are made against this *colorful* discrimination (or maybe not that serious though).

Comment: ES (for "español") is more standard for Spanish. In general we should follow some standard like the [ISO639 language codes.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)