# Why are all the Stacks Overflows are svgified except pt.SO?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, portuguese-stackoverflow

SO, ru.SO, ja.SO are svigified:

[image][image][image]

But not pt.SO:

[image]

It seems to use semi-old design (can be seen by looking at the logo).

That's also strange because pt.SO is older than ja.SO or ru.SO, but still not svgified.

P.S I don't know to which word I should append "s", so I've written Stacks Overflows, just in case.

Comment: edit to say SO site**s**.

Comment: "That's also strange because pt.SO is older than ja.SO or ru.SO, but still not svgified." Why is that strange? ja.SO & ru.SO likely launched with the new designs, pt.SO only launched with part of the new design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a new design waiting in the wings for PT.SO. It'll be public when the site graduates.

Comment: And when The Site graduates?

Comment: 6-8 weeks of course, @nicael. ;)

Comment: Is this the new `.less` designs? Is there a list of the ones waiting anywhere?

Comment: This looks  like completed?

Comment: Technically it was completed when I wrote this answer, @nicael - the SVG was waiting on graduation, which has now occurred.